# How do I fix my ANTLR Parser to separate comments from multiplication?

Tags: parsing, comments, antlr4, grammar, lexer

I'm using ANTLR4 to try to parse code that has asterisk-leading comments, like:

```
* This is a comment
```

I was initially having issues with multiplication expressions getting mistaken for these comments, so decided to make my lexer rule:

```
LINE_COMMENT : '\r\n' '*' ~[\r\n]* ;
```

This forces there to be a newline so it doesn't see 2 * 3, with '* 3' being a comment.
This worked just fine until I had code that starts with a comment on the first line, which does not have a newline to begin with. For example:

```
* This is the first line of the code's file\r\n
* This is the second line of the codes's file\r\n
```

I have also tried the {getCharPositionInLine==x}? to make sure that it only recognizes a comment if there is an asterisk or spaces/tabs coming first in the current line. This works when using

```
antlr4 *.g4
```

, but will not work with my JavaScript parser generated using

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript *.g4
```

Is there a way to get the same results of {getCharPositionInLine==x}? with my JavaScript parser or some way to prevent multiplication from being recognized as a comment? I should also mention that this coding language doesn't use semicolons at the end of lines.

I've tried playing around with this simple grammar, but I haven't had any luck.

```
grammar wow;

program : expression | Comment ;
expression : expression '*' expression
           | NUMBER ;

Comment : '*' ~[\r\n]*;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
Asterisk : '*' ;
Space : ' ' -> skip;
```

and using a test file: test.txt

```
5 * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the comment rule match at least one more non-whitespace character, otherwise it could match the same content as the `Asterisk` rule, like so:

```
Comment: '*' ' '* ~[\r\n]+;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this does not work. It will still recognize multiplication, such as '5 * 5' as a comment, the '* 5' all the way to the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Do comments have to be at the beginning of line?

- If so you can check it with `this._tokenStartCharPositionInLine == 0` and have lexer rule like this
  `Comment : '*' ~[\r\n]* {this._tokenStartCharPositionInLine == 0}?;`
- If not, you should gather information about previous tokens, which could allow us to have multiplication (for example your `NUMBER` rule), so you should write something like (java code)

  ```
  @lexer::members {
      private static final Set<Integer> MULTIPLIABLE_TOKENS = new HashSet<>();
      static {
          MULTIPLIABLE_TOKENS.add(NUMBER);
      }

      private boolean canBeMultiplied = false;

      @Override
      public void emit(final Token token) {
          final int type = token.getType();
          if (type != Whitespace && type != Newline) {  // skip ws tokens from consideration
              canBeMultiplied = MULTIPLIABLE_TOKENS.contains(type);
          }
          super.emit(token);
      }

  }

  Comment : {!canBeMultiplied}? '*' ~[\r\n]*;
  ```

## UPDATE

If you need function analogs for JavaScript, take a look into the [sources](https://www.antlr.org/download/index.html) -> Lexer.js